# How to make PDE file in Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, processing

I have a Java GUI project in `netbeans` and I want to make Processing Development Environment (PDE) file of it. I have searched everywhere but couldn't find the solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.pde` file is really just a text file with a `.pde` extension. You can prove this by opening up a `.pde` file in a basic text editor like notepad or JEdit.

So to create a `.pde` file, you just have to print some Processing code to a text file and give it a name that ends with `.pde`.

If you have file associations set up (which happens automatically when you install Processing), then the Processing editor will open `.pde` files be default.

The Processing editor expects `.pde` files to be in a folder with the same name as the `.pde` file, but I think it will actually detect this and move it for you, so that might not be strictly necessary.

**Edit:** But I wonder if that's what you're actually asking. If what you're actually asking is how to use Processing as a Java library in Netbeans, then that's a different question.

If that is what you're asking, then you're no longer using a `.pde` file. Instead, you'll need to create a Java project, then add the Processing library jars (located in the Processing directory) to your classpath. After that you can call Processing from Java, and most projects will start with a class that extends `PApplet`. That class contains your sketch code, and you launch it by calling `PApplet.main("YourSketchNameHere");` from the regular `main()` method.

Comment: There was some confusion between processing file and java projects. I thought them as same. Now its clear. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Ateeq24 No problem. If this answer helped you, feel free to upvote it and mark it correct so other people can find it in the future.